# Render ImageData from canvas context.getImageData in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

In a React component how can I render an image created using canvas?

```
componentWillMount () {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  canvas.width = 256
  canvas.height = 256
  // omitted canvas painting code
  const image = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  this.setState({image})
}

render() {
  return ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can render it directly in the render method. But you can draw it if you use componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate hooks if you are setting it with state.

```js
class Hi extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  componentWillMount () {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.width = 256
    canvas.height = 256
    context.rect(20,20,150,100);
    context.stroke();
    const image = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    this.setState({image})
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const context = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.putImageData(this.state.image, 0, 0);
  }
  render() {
    return <canvas ref="canvas" />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hi />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please convert your `canvas` content to [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) using [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), then you can render the image with an `img` tag passing the data URI as `src` attribute:

```
<img src={this.state.dataURI} />
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  componentWillMount () {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.width = 256
    canvas.height = 256
    
    const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    const radius = 70;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();

    const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL()
    this.setState({dataURI})
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={this.state.dataURI} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```